# How to change the y_scale in geom_col?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting a graph that is showing me a scale between 0 and 100. The variable mean_health which is on the y-axis ranges between 70 and 80, therefore, i would like to limit the scale to that range. Could someone please help me through it?

Here is my code:

```
ggplot(a, aes(y=mean_health, fill= Year)) + 
  geom_col(aes(class), position = "dodge")
```

I tried to change the scale with the line below but it didn't work:

```
 scale_y_continuous(limits = c(70, 80), breaks = seq(70, 80, by = 2))
```

Here is my data:

```
structure(list(class = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Upper-middle class", 
"Lower-middle class", "Working class"), class = "factor"), Year = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Prior 2009", "Post 2008"), class = "factor"), 
    mean_health = c(78.6882398353062, 78.3941867397288, 77.3571107110711, 
    76.3957410743853, 73.2470989724234, 71.866548366062)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), groups = structure(list(class = structure(1:3, .Label = c("Upper-middle class", 
"Lower-middle class", "Working class"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(
    1:2, 3:4, 5:6), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
ggplot(a, aes(y=mean_health, fill= Year)) + 
  geom_col(aes(class), position = "dodge")+
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(70, 80))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(70, 80, by = 2))
```

Output:

[image]